# MongoError: WriteConflict

Tags: node.js, mongodb, transactions

When i send multi request from frontend (`react`) to backend (`nodejs`) simultaneously, the server gives me this error `MongoError: WriteConflict`. i am using `transaction` when i want to update some data in database:

code:

```
const db = require("../../utils/database-connection/database");
const FollowersFollowing = require("../../models/followers-following/followers-following-models");

  const session = db.client().startSession();
  session.startTransaction();

      let whoFollowed;

      try {
        whoFollowed = await FollowersFollowing.updateFollow(
          userId,
          targetUserId,
          { session },
          "follow"
        );

        await Notice.updateNotice(
          userId,
          targetUserId,
          { session },
          "showUserOnTargetUserNotice"
        );

        await session.commitTransaction();
        session.endSession();
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        await session.abortTransaction();

        return next(
          new HttpError("could not follow the user, please try again.", 500)
        );
      }
```

all things works fine but when i want to send multi request (just for testing) the server throw this error.

Answer (score -1):

See https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/transactions/ for the correct usage patterns. You must retry on those errors which withTransaction helper does for you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/9540925/d-sm Thanks, i solved that